# How to add one value hardcoded in a return statement in xquery

Tags: xquery

I have a function in which a return statement is already written as :-

```
return 
  if (fn:count($somevariable1) eq 1) 
  then some-method($var1, $var2, $var3) 
  else fn:concat(...some string values..)
```

The above statement is written inside a function. And some-method is another function which is declared somewhere. Now I want to hardcode a value just after the if statement and before the else statement. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning just the product of `some-method($var1, $var2, $var3)`, you want to return a sequence that also includes a hard-coded string value?

You can return a [sequence of values](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xquery-31-20170321/#id-sequence-expressions), just separate with a comma and wrap with parenthesis.

```
if (fn:count($somevariable1) eq 1) 
then ( some-method($var1, $var2, $var3), "my hardcoded value" )
else fn:concat(...some string values..)
```

Comment: But when i try this, do i need to make any changes where some-method is declared?

Comment: another error when i m trying to run it is :  SQL-NOCOLUMN: Column not found : my hardcoded value

Comment: It sounds like I may not have understood what you were looking to do. I thought that you wanted to execute a method and also return a string. Can you update the question with more info? Also, what are you running this code in? It isn’t clear how the hard coded value is giving SQL errors.

Comment: So, if you want to return whatever comes back from the “some-method()” as well as a hard coded value, then my answer should do it. It isn’t clear why you were asking about modifying the “some-method()”, unless maybe you had put the hard coded value as a 4th parameter instead of after the call to that method?

Comment: yes i have tried what you provided but its giving the column not found error.

Comment: I have provided a means of doing what you have asked. If you are having trouble applying what is returned, you need to provide some more information about how/what is being done with it. For instance, if this is a return statement for an XQuery module in SQL Server that has an expectation about how to convert the data into rows and columns for an SQL interface, that would be helpful information.